# Odoo 11 - Action Server

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Here is my code for a custom action declaration:

```
        <record id="scheduler_synchronization_update_school_and_grade" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Action automatisee ...</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_ecole_partner_school"/>
            <field name="code">model.run_grade_establishment_smartbambi()</field>
            <field name="active" eval="False"/>
        </record>
```

Here is the start of my function which is called:

[image]

Here is the error message when I update my custom module on the server:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « use_relational_model »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (516559, 1, null, 1, 2020-01-02 14:56:39.02145, null, 2020-01-02 14:56:39.02145, ir.actions.server, Action automatisee ..., null, action, model.run_grade_establishment_smartbambi(), 5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, object_write, null, null, 397, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, ir_cron, null)
" while parsing /opt/odoo11/addons-odoo/Odoo/ecole/data/actions.xml:33, near
<record id="scheduler_synchronization_update_school_and_grade" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Action automatisee ...</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_ecole_partner_school"/>
            <field name="code">model.run_grade_establishment_smartbambi()</field>
            <field name="active" eval="False"/>
        </record>
```

Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ? I can't find anything on the internet

thank you so much

EDIT :

I have solved my problem. 
With PGAdmin 4, the use_relational_model field was required. I have deactivate the required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `state` field in the cron definition. This is the "Action To Do" field. Try following:

```
    <record id="scheduler_synchronization_update_school_and_grade" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Action automatisee ...</field>
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="interval_type">days</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_ecole_partner_school"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">model.run_grade_establishment_smartbambi()</field>
        <field name="active" eval="False"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was trying to add the line you mentioned in the same place, and the error message was the same

Comment: `use_relational_model` is a field in `ir.actions.server` model in Odoo v10, in your code you are trying to create `ir.cron` which is different model, unless you have other codes `/opt/odoo11/addons-odoo/Odoo/ecole/data/actions.xml` which is creating `ir.actions.server` record, this particular error is not generated by your shared code.

Comment: In my "action.xml" file, I have 3 automated actions based on the "ir.cron" model. The other two work fine, the only one that doesn't work is this one. However, I did a copy and paste and changed the id and the call to the function. The error message concerning this field "use_relationnal_model" is visible when updating my custom module

Comment: I have one ir.action.server declaration but there are any link except that it's same model "ecole.partner.school"